# jquery elements that were added with .after() method do not trigger events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-after

This is the code:

```
<s:file name="upload"  id="upload"></s:file>
  $('input[id^="upload"]').change(function(){
        alert("aa");
        $(this).after('<input type="file" name="upload_3" id="upload_3"/>');
        alert($("#upload_3").attr("name"));
    });
    $('input[id^="upload"]').click(function(){
        alert("click");
    });
```

When I click "upload" element, it triggers the `click` and `change` events, and alerts "aa" and "upload_3". It then added `<input type="file" name="upload_3" id="upload_3"/>` after the "upload" element in HTML. But when I click the newly added element ("upload_3" element), the `click` and `change` even do not trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are bound to elements while loading the DOM(Static elements). While you are adding some element dynamically you need to attach the events yourself.

Following code will bind a click event to the dynamically added element using [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

```
$(this).after('<input type="file" name="upload_3" id="upload_3"/>').bind('click', function(){
    alert('Click event fired for the new element');
});
```

You can also use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.

From [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and
>   attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page.

```
$(this).after('<input type="file" name="upload_3" id="upload_3"/>').on('click', function(){
    alert('Click event fired for the new element');
});
```

Comment: thanks,but when i used on('click', function()...); display error "$(...).on is not a function",and no effect while bind('click', function()....); work well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to attach the event handlers to the dynamically appended elements. Using `jQuery`, the `.on()` method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the `jQuery object`. As of `jQuery 1.7`, the `.on()` method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.

This might help you:

```
$(document).on('click','input[id^="upload"]',function(){
    alert("click");
});
```

Also have a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Comment: thaks very much,but didn't work as expected, TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function,please help me,thanks

Comment: @user2245634 Can you post how your script looks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a delegated event handler in this case; this can be done by using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on):

```
 $('#parent').on('click', 'input[id^="upload"]', function() {
     // do your stuff here
 });
```

In this case, the `#parent` node refers to the closest parent of your `<input>` elements. The click event is first handled by this parent node and then translated before it calls your click handler to make sure `this` references the correct node.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "on" or "live" for the elements that are added to the DOM on the fly. but "on" is preferred.

```
$('input[id^="upload"]').change(function(){
    var _this = $(this)
    $('<input type="file" name="upload_3" id="upload_3"/>').insertAfter(_this);
    });

$(document).on('click','input[id^="upload"]',function(){
    // do your stuff
});
```